# HTML selection issue

Tags: html, css

I am running front end tests using cucumber on my web site. Currently, I would like to click a div element which is present as below

```
<div class=full>
<div class=half>
 <div class=product-image></div>
</div>
<div class=half>
 <div class=product-image></div>
</div>
<div class=half>
 <div class=product-image></div>
</div>
<div class=half>
 <div class=product-image></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to select the first product-image class uniquely. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2):

is this how you want ???...

```css
.product-image{
  height : 50px;
  width : 100px;
  background-color : red;
  margin : 5px;
}

.full .half:first-child .product-image{
  background-color : green;
}
```

```html
<div class=full>
  <div class=half>
    <div class=product-image></div>
  </div>
  <div class=half>
    <div class=product-image></div>
  </div>
  <div class=half>
    <div class=product-image></div>
  </div>
  <div class=half>
    <div class=product-image></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may select it like this:

```
.full > div:first-child .product-image{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.full .half:first-child .product-image{
  ...code
}
```